# Fill form with data inside in array with php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

My idea is to get the complete address about the user  with a select element, actually I have a variable that has all the addresses `$all = (array)$this->_user->getAddressCollection();` and if i make a tiny script only to get the response, the response looks like below:

[image]

I use that variable in a foreach to get the id of the address and the addresses name:

```
 <select class="addrs">
    <?
      foreach($all as $addre => $info):
     ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $info->getIdCustomerAddress(); ?>">
          <?php echo $info->getAddress1() . ' ' .  $info->getAddress2() . ' - ' .
                                $info->getAddress3(); ?>
      </option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>`
```

Since here, I dont know how to fill a form when user select one of the addresses are display on the select

Comment: This `select` element is inside a form right?

Comment: @MehdiBounya no, is not inside of!!

Comment: Can you explain more then, what form are you talking about? do you mean when the user selects a value from the `select` dropdown it gets copied to another input?

Comment: @MehdiBounya, that is my intention when the user select a value, the complete information will loaded on inputs

Comment: @MehdiBounya in the response exist two values `497290` and `538767` they are the id's from that id's I want to fill the inputs

Comment: You need to provide more information. What exactly do you want to fill? What form are you talking about, since your code has only a select? When do you want this filling to happen? When the user selects an option or when he sends the form?